# how do i update column position into table with several conditions mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-update, sql-order-by

I have a table like this:

```
+----+------------+-------------+----------+------------+-----------+
| id | product_id | category_id | position | createdAt  | status_id |
+----+------------+-------------+----------+------------+-----------+
|  1 |        246 |           1 |        1 | 2020-01-01 |         1 |
|  2 |        247 |           1 |        2 | 2020-01-02 |         0 |
|  3 |        248 |           8 |        3 | 2020-01-03 |         1 |
|  4 |        249 |           8 |        4 | 2020-01-04 |         0 |
|  5 |        250 |           1 |        5 | 2020-01-04 |         1 |
|  6 |        251 |           8 |        6 | 2020-01-05 |         1 |
+----+------------+-------------+----------+------------+-----------+
```

how do i make an order and update the column position for product_id with category_id = 8 and status_id = 1, but if status_id being updated from 1 to 0, then remove the order on that product_id, based on that table, my expected result should be like this:

```
+----+------------+-------------+----------+------------+-----------+
| id | product_id | category_id | position | createdAt  | status_id |
+----+------------+-------------+----------+------------+-----------+
|  1 |        246 |           1 |        1 | 2020-01-01 |         1 |
|  2 |        247 |           1 |        2 | 2020-01-02 |         0 |
|  3 |        248 |           8 |        1 | 2020-01-03 |         1 |
|  4 |        249 |           8 |        4 | 2020-01-04 |         0 |
|  5 |        250 |           1 |        5 | 2020-01-04 |         1 |
|  6 |        251 |           8 |        2 | 2020-01-05 |         1 |
+----+------------+-------------+----------+------------+-----------+
```

i've tried with

```
    UPDATE position SET position = (how to order it) 
    WHERE category_id = 8 and status_id = 1
```

UPDATE :
i've tried with this :

```
UPDATE product_categories pc1 SET pc1.position = 
(SELECT  (@row:=@row+1) FROM product_categories pc2 WHERE
pc2.status = 1 AND pc2.category_id = 8 ORDER BY pc2.createdAt);
```

but it produces an error like this `Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'pc1' for update in FROM clause`

UPDATE: I've tried with this

```
SET @row := 0;
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
UPDATE product_categories pc1 SET pc1.position = 
(SELECT  (@row:=@row+1) FROM (SELECT pc2.product_id FROM product_categories pc2 WHERE
pc2.status = 1 AND pc2.category_id = 8 ORDER BY pc2.createdAt) AS a);
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 1;
```

and it appears an error like this : `Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row`

Comment: Your logic is unclear, and I suggest that spend a few minutes to explain it.

Comment: done, i think i can ignore the last logic, thank you for the reminder sir

Comment: i put the update because i've tried with another sight

Comment: What MySQL version?

Comment: im using 5.7 sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to update using this:

```
UPDATE product_categories a 
  JOIN
     (SELECT @row:=@row+1 pos, b.* 
      FROM product_categories b 
      WHERE category_id=8 AND status_id=1) b
   ON a.id=b.id 
   AND a.product_id=b.product_id 
   AND a.category_id=b.category_id
   AND a.status_id=b.status_id
SET a.position=b.pos;
```

Here's a demo fiddle:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=8bc4d1844aff2fbfa0210c4c760cd07a